# What's more important to have seen before Civil War: Daredevil S2 or Agent Carter S2?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, suggested-order

My best friend has been lagging behind on her MCU TV shows lately. She's definitely going to be caught up with Agents of SHIELD before seeing Civil War, but she may not have time to watch both Agent Carter S2 and Daredevil S2. On the one hand, Agent Carter is a Captain America character, but on the other hand, Daredevil has been dropping some Civil War-esque ideas this season...

**Without any spoilers, please,** if she only has time to watch Agent Carter S2 or Daredevil S2 before seeing Civil War, which one would be more valuable to have seen before the movie?

Comment: Well, Agent Carter fits the normal MCU audience, whereas Daredevil is TVMA and not family friendly, so it's less likely fans would _need_ to watch Daredevil, you know?

Answer (score 11):

Having seen all of both shows, I can tell you with a high degree of confidence that you should just watch whichever you like more, because neither will matter.

Marvel's movie and TV divisions are run by two separate groups within the company, and while they exist in a shared universe, they're not exactly buddy-buddy at this point. It's been firmly established by multiple directors and producers that you will never need to watch any TV shows before seeing a movie. They seem to have taken this to a rather extreme degree - nothing that happens on the small screen will ever be referenced on the big one. (At least, that's the current policy -- that might change in the future but we're not holding our breath.)

For what it's worth, though, *Agent Carter* is set so far in the past that there's almost no chance it will impact any future movies. *Daredevil*, at least, is set somewhere around the current time. However, I can't think of a single plot point that happened in *Daredevil Season 2* that's going to impact *Civil War*.

---

Just my opinion: if you have to pick, pick *Daredevil*. But only because it's a better show.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that there's not even any crossover between the Netflix series and the rest too.. Very sad. :(

Comment: There hasn't been *yet*, apart from the obvious fact that they take place in the same NYC as *Avengers*...

Comment: There's a quote somewhere out there of Kevin Feige saying that there's no plans whatsoever to cross over the Netflix series and other Marvel TV because they're ran by two separate entities!

Comment: and there was a quote from several different people that there were no plans to cross over *Flash* and *Supergirl* because they were on different networks... until it happened.

Comment: Aside from the fact they had the same showrunner, which most likely made a huge difference. :p